# Dynamic keyboard in PHP Telegram bot

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I have this snippet for creating dynamic keyboard:

```
            $keyboard_array = [];
            foreach ($verse_arr['items'] as $item) {
                    $keyboard_array[] = ["text" => '"'. $item['poem']['verse-r'] . '
                    ' . $item['article']['verse-l'] . '
                    ' . $item['article']['poet'] . '
                    ' . $item['article']['book'] . '"' , "callback_data" => '"'.$item['article_id'].'"'];
            }
            $current = print_r($keyboard_array,true);
            $file = 'keyboard.log';
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
            apiRequestJson("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => "Search results: ", 'reply_markup' =>  new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                [
                    'inline_keyboard' => [$keyboard_array]
                ])));
```

As you can see in rows 8-10 I write the results to a file and everything looks fine there. But the message doesn't get through.The text is in UTF-8 and Persian by the way.

I hope you can help me with this.

Regards,

Comment: By the way I tried both: json_encode( new InlineKeyboardMarkup and new InlineKeyboardMarkup

Comment: Ok found out the solution myself. It was with the double quoutes around parameters' values:  $keyboard_array[] = ["text" => '"'. $item['poem']['verse-r'] . '
                    ' . $item['article']['verse-l'] . '
                    ' . $item['article']['poet'] . '
                    ' . $item['article']['book'] . '"' , "callback_data" => '"'.$item['article_id'].'"'];
            }